# Doubly linked list iterators implementaion approach

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I have implemented a doubly linked list with iterators(regular and const) and it seems working ok, but I can't understand several things:

1) As I know one of the ways to implement iterators is inherit from `std::iterator< ... >` mentioning in template parameters all the necessary types, then typedef them in your class ... but why we need `difference_type` of two iterators ? bidirectional iterator must not overload `operator - ()` inside so is it ok to not remove difference type ?

2) I know that it's not the best approach to duplicate logic of similar things (in my case regular iterator and const_iterator are two different classes) but that's what I did at the moment due to my basic knowledge about c++ templates. I made `const_iterator` as a friend for `iterator` and made implicit conversions from `T` (node value type) to `const T` using special constructor `const_iterator(iterator &other)` so when returning references and pointers from `operator *()` it and `operator->()` it automatically converts internal `ptr->_node_value` (list node data) to const version. Is this approach ok enough ??

```
template <typename T>
struct DLList_node
{
    T _node_value;
    DLList_node<T> *_next, *_prev;
    DLList_node<T>(const T& = T(), DLList_node<T> * = NULL, DLList_node<T> * = NULL);   
};

template <typename T>
class DLList;

//non-const regular iterator
template<typename T>
class DLList_iterator;

//const iterator
template<typename T>
class DLList_const_iterator;

template<typename T>
class DLList_iterator :
    public std::iterator< std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T, T*, T& >
{
    public:
        friend class DLList<T>;
        //const iterator must have access to node pointer
        friend class DLList_const_iterator<T>;  
        typedef T                               value_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t                       difference_type;
        typedef T*                              pointer;
        typedef T&                              reference;
        typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef DLList_node<T>*                 node_ptr;           

        DLList_iterator()
        : ptr(NULL)
        {}

        DLList_iterator(node_ptr _ptr): ptr(_ptr)
        {}

        reference operator*() const
        {
            assert(ptr != NULL && "list iterator not dereferencable!");
            return ptr->_node_value;
        }

        pointer operator->() const
        {
            assert(ptr != NULL && "list iterator not dereferencable!");
            return &(ptr->_node_value);
        }

        bool operator == (const DLList_iterator& other) const
        {
            return ptr == other.ptr;
        }

        bool operator != (const DLList_iterator& other) const
        {
            return ptr != other.ptr;
        }

        //pre incerement
        DLList_iterator& operator++()
        {
            assert(ptr != NULL && "list iterator not incrementable!");
            ptr = ptr->_next;
            return *this;
        }

        //post increment
        DLList_iterator operator++(int) 
        {
            assert(ptr != NULL && "list iterator not incrementable!");
            DLList_iterator tmp(*this);
            ptr = ptr->_next;
            return tmp; 
        }

        DLList_iterator& operator--() 
        {
            assert(ptr != NULL && "list iterator not decrementable!");
            ptr = ptr->_prev;
            return *this;
        }

        DLList_iterator operator--(int) 
        {
            assert(ptr != NULL && "list iterator not decrementable!");
            DLList_iterator tmp(*this);
            ptr = ptr->_prev;
            return tmp; 
        }

    private:
        node_ptr ptr;
};


//const iterator
template<typename T>
class DLList_const_iterator :
    public std::iterator< std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, const T, const T*, const T& >
{
    public:
        friend class DLList<T>; 
        typedef const T                         value_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t                       difference_type;
        typedef const T*                        const_pointer;
        typedef const T&                        const_reference;
        typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;      
        typedef DLList_node<T>*                 node_ptr;   

        DLList_const_iterator()
        : cptr(NULL)
        {}

        DLList_const_iterator(DLList_iterator<T>& _iter): cptr(_iter.ptr)
        {}

        DLList_const_iterator(node_ptr _ptr): cptr(_ptr)
        {}

        const_reference operator*() const
        {
            assert(cptr != NULL && "list iterator not dereferencable!");
            return cptr->_node_value;
        }

        const_pointer operator->() const
        {
            assert(cptr != NULL && "list iterator not dereferencable!");
            return &(cptr->_node_value);
        }

        bool operator == (const DLList_const_iterator & other) const
        {
            return cptr == other.cptr;
        }

        bool operator != (const DLList_const_iterator & other) const
        {
            return cptr != other.cptr;
        }

        //pre incerement
        DLList_const_iterator & operator++()
        {
            assert(cptr != NULL && "list iterator not incrementable!");
            cptr = cptr->_next;
            return *this;
        }

        //post increment
        DLList_const_iterator operator++(int) 
        {
            assert(cptr != NULL && "list iterator not incrementable!");
            DLList_const_iterator tmp(*this);
            cptr = cptr->_next;
            return tmp; 
        }

        DLList_const_iterator & operator--() 
        {
            assert(cptr != NULL && "list iterator not decrementable!");
            cptr = cptr->_prev;
            return *this;
        }

        DLList_const_iterator operator--(int) 
        {
            assert(cptr != NULL && "list iterator not decrementable!");
            DLList_iterator tmp(*this);
            cptr = cptr->_prev;
            return tmp; 
        }       

    private:
        node_ptr cptr;
};

template <typename T>
class DLList
{
    private:
         node_ptr _begin, _tail;
    public:
        typedef DLList_iterator<T> iterator;
        typedef DLList_const_iterator<T> const_iterator;
        typedef DLList_node<T>* node_ptr;           
        typedef DLList_node<T> node;

        typedef typename DLList_iterator<T>::value_type         value_type;
        typedef typename DLList_iterator<T>::difference_type    difference_type;
        typedef typename DLList_iterator<T>::pointer            pointer;
        typedef typename DLList_iterator<T>::reference          reference;

        typedef typename DLList_const_iterator<T>::const_pointer    const_pointer;
        typedef typename DLList_const_iterator<T>::const_reference  const_reference;

    //member functions and constructors here        
    //...
};
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `std::list` or at the very least, looking at the iterator implementation there?

Comment: As to your first question, I believe `std::advance` requires a `difference_type`.

Comment: I have looked to std::list iterators implementations but it's the way too complicated, they also uses two classes but how do they perform conversion from non-const iterator to const one ? `list<int>::iterator i = l.begin(); list<int>::const_iterator = i;`

Answer (score 0):

> 1) As I know one of the ways to implement iterators is inherit from std::iterator< ... > mentioning in template parameters all the necessary types,

Yes.

> then typedef them in your class ...

No. That's why you inherit from `std::iterator` so you don't have to bother doing that.

> but why we need difference_type of two iterators ?

Note that `std::iterator` defaults most of the standard types. You only need to specify a difference type if you are doing something funky and none standard.

> bidirectional iterator must not overload operator - () inside so is it ok to not remove difference type ?

You don't need to mention any of the types. `std::iterator` does all that work for you.

> 2) I know that it's not the best approach to duplicate logic of similar things (in my case regular iterator and const_iterator are two different classes) but that's what I did at the moment due to my basic knowledge about c++ templates.

Looking at your class's they are basically the same apart from some differences in retrieval. Why not move all the same code into a base class.

```
template<typename T>
class DLList_Base_iterator :
    public std::iterator< std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T, T*, T& >
{
      // Common code
      protected:  // allow all concrete iterators to see pointer.
          node_ptr ptr;
};
template<typename T>
class DLList_iterator : public DLList_Base_iterator<T>
{
    DLList_iterator():              public DLList_Base_iterator<T>(NULL) {}
    DLList_iterator(node_ptr _ptr): public DLList_Base_iterator<T>(_ptr) {}

    reference operator*()        const  {return cptr->_node_value;}
    pointer   operator->()       const  {return &(cptr->_node_value);}
};
template<typename T>
class DLList_const_iterator : public DLList_Base_iterator<T>
{
    DLList_const_iterator():              public DLList_Base_iterator<T>(NULL) {}
    DLList_const_iterator(node_ptr _ptr): public DLList_Base_iterator<T>(_ptr) {}
    const_reference operator*()  const {return cptr->_node_value;}
    const_pointer   operator->() const {return &(cptr->_node_value);}
};
```

> I made const_iterator as a friend for iterator and made implicit conversions from T (node value type) to const T using special constructor const_iterator(iterator &other) so when returning references and pointers from operator *() it and operator->() it automatically converts internal ptr->_node_value (list node data) to const version. Is this approach ok enough ??

I would just add a conversion operator to the non-const iterator that allows you to convert it to a const version.

```
template<typename T>
class DLList_iterator : public DLList_Base_iterator<T>
{
    operator DLList_const_iterator<T> {
        return DLList_const_iterator<T>(cptr);
    }
};
```